# Factorialize a Number

Tags: javascript, math, factorial

I'm taking the freecodecamp course one of the exercises it's to create a `Factorialize` function, I know there is several ways to do it just not sure what this one keeps returning **5**

```
function factorialize(num) {
    var myMax = num;
    var myCounter = 1;
    var myTotal = 0;

    for (i = 0; i>= myMax; i++) {
        num = myCounter * (myCounter + 1);
        myCounter++;
    }
    return num;
}

factorialize(5);
```

Comment: We would want you to complete this challenge. Else whats the point of the codecamp ;)

Comment: I know and I find another way to do it, just it´s bothering me this one is not working even if the Math to get the number is right, my problem is the return

Comment: One hint Try recursion code gets nice. Best way to factorials !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a recursive solution of your problem:

```
function factorialize(num) {
    if(num <= 1) {
        return num
    } else {
        return num * factorialize(num-1) 
    }
}

factorialize(5)
```

This is the iterative solution:

```
function factorialize(num) {
    var cnt = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= num ; i++) {
        cnt *= i;
    }
    return cnt;
}

factorialize(5)
```

with argument 5, it will return the 5! or 120.

Comment: thanks! still getting familiar with recursive functions

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, why your function is returning 5:
Your function never reaches the inner part of the for-loop because your testing if i is greater than myMax instead of less than.
So you are just returning your input parameter which is five.

But the loop does not calculate the factorial of num, it only multiplies (num+1)  with (num+2);

Answer (score 1):

My solution in compliance with [convention for empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product)

```
function factorializer(int) {
    if (int <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return int * factorializer(int - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you consider another approach.

This solution features a very short - cut to show what is possible to get with an recursive style and a implicit type conversion:

```
function f(n) { return +!~-n || n * f(n - 1); }
```

- + convert to number
- ! not
- ~ not bitwise
- - negative

```js
function f(n) { return +!~-n || n * f(n - 1); }

var i;
for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    console.log(f(i));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to solve this challenge and I know it is neither the shortest nor the easiest but it is still a valid way.

```
function factorialiaze(num){
var myArr = []; //declaring an array.
if(num === 0 || num === 1){
return 1;
}
if (num < 0){ //for negative numbers.
return "N/A";
}
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++){ // creating an array.
     myArr.push(i);
}
// Reducing myArr to a single value via .reduce:
num = myArr.reduce(function(a,b){
     return a * b;
 });
return num;
}
factorialiaze(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
const factorialize = (num) =>  num === 0 ? 1 : num * factorialize(num-1)
```

Use it like this:

```
factorialize(5) // returns 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function factorialize(num) {
  var value = 1;
    if(num === 1 || num ===0) {
      return value;
    } else {
      for(var i = 1; i<num; i++) {
        value *= i;
      }
      return num * value;
  }
}
factorialize(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// My solution

const factorialize = num => {
    let newNum = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        newNum *= i
    }
    return newNum;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I love syntactic sugar, so

```
let factorialize = num => num <= 1 ? num : num * factorialize(num -1)
factorialize(5)
```